# Request for assistance on finishing the proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n x_n = 0$ given some initial conditions.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $\{x_n\}$ denote a sequence such that:
>   $$
> \exists N \in \Bbb N: \forall n > N \implies 0 < x_{n+1} < x_n
> $$
>   And the sequence $\{y_n\}$ is convergent, where $\{y_n\}$ is given by:
>   $$
> y_n = \sum_{k=1}^n x_n
> $$
>   Prove that:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty} n x_n =0
> $$

Below is what I've done so far.

Start with the first fact. We are given that a sequence $x_n$ is monotonically decreasing starting from some $N$. That by Weierstrass theorem means that the sequence is convergent to some $x_0 > 0$, namely:
$$
\exists x_0 \in\Bbb R_{>0}:\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x_0 \tag1
$$

Also it is bounded:
$$
\exists m, M \in \Bbb R,\ \forall n \in \Bbb N:m \le x_n \le M \tag2
$$

We are also given that the sum is convergent, hence:
$$
\exists L \in \Bbb R:\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n x_k = L \tag3
$$

Combining both facts above we may fix any $\epsilon > 0$ and find $N$ such that:
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists N \in \Bbb N: \forall m, n > N \implies
\begin{cases}
|x_n| < \epsilon \\
|y_n - y_m| < \epsilon
\end{cases}
$$

By convergence we also have that $\{y_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Since both sequences converge we as well know that for $\{x_n\}$:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\inf x_n = x_0\tag4
$$
And for $y_n$:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup y_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\inf y_n = L \tag5
$$

I've been playing around with those properties for a long time yet, but I couldn't find a way to combine them in order to show that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}nx_n = 0
$$

Could someone please assist me on that? I would prefer a hint rather than a complete proof. Thank you!

Comment: A monotonically decreasing sequence doesn't imply it tends to $0$. However, you could use the fact that $y_n$ convereges and hence $x_n$ must converge to $0$. Unless I'm missing something about Weierstrass Theorem. Which one is it? About 8 on wikipedia disambiguation page

Comment: $n < 2^n$ so Cauchy Condensation might work

Comment: @Anvit By this theorem I mean that  any monotonic sequence $\{x_n\}$ has a finite limit in case it's bounded.

Comment: @Anvit well actually since $x_{n+1} > 0$ and $x_n > x_{n+1}$ it should mean convergence to $0$, shouldn't it?

Comment: No, that stament alone doesn't work, define $z_n = 1 + x_n$. $z_n$ also satifies the above properties but converges to 1 (if $x_n$ converegs to $0$)

Comment: @Anvit is right when he says that $0 \lt x_{n+1} \lt  x_n $ doesn't imply that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$. $x_n = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$ is a counter exemple. On the other hand, the fact that $y_n$ is convergent is a sufficient condition for $x_n$ convergence to $0$

Comment: @Anvit, i see, thanks for clarification. I've updated the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\lim_{n\to\inf} (y_{2n}-y_n) = 0$
Comment if you require more hints

Also, as I said, you can also use Cauchy Condensation test as an Alternative solution

Comment: Thank you, I've added an answer to this question, hopefully correct.

Answer (score 0):

My try to use hint by **@Anvit**

> **Lemma**:
>   $$
> \exists L \in \Bbb R: \lim_{n\to\infty} y_n= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n x_n = L \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0
> $$

Proof. Since $\{y_n\}$ converges it must satisfy Cauchy Criterion. Consider the following:
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists N \in \Bbb N: \forall n, m > N \implies |y_n -y_m| < \epsilon
$$

Take $m=n-1$, then we have that:
$$
|x_n| = |y_n - y_{n-1}| < \epsilon
$$
Which would mean:
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists N \in\Bbb N: \forall n > N \implies |x_n| < \epsilon \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0
$$

So by Lemma we obtain that $x_n$ is convergent to $0$:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = 0
$$
As desired $\Box$.

---

Consider $\{y_n\}$ and $m = 2n > n$, then by Cauchy Criterion:
$$
\begin{align}
|y_n - y_m| &= |y_m - y_n| \\
&= |y_{2n} - y_n| \\ 
&= \left| \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}x_k \right| \\
&= \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}x_k < \epsilon
\end{align}
$$

We know that $x_n > 0$ and is monotonically decreasing towards $0$ starting from some $N$ and thus:
$$
\underbrace{x_{2n} + x_{2n} + \cdots + x_{2n}}_{n\ \text{times}} < x_{n+1} + x_{n+2} + \cdots + x_{2n-1} + x_{2n} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}x_k < \epsilon \\
nx_{2n} < \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}x_k < \epsilon \\
2n\cdot x_{2n} < 2\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}x_k < 2\epsilon
$$

We know that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} 2\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}x_k = 0
$$

Applying squeeze theorem to that:
$$
0 \le \lim_{n\to\infty} 2n\cdot x_{2n} \le \lim_{n\to\infty} 2\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}x_k
$$

Using the fact that $x_n$ is monotonically decreasing we may conclude:
$$
0 \le \lim_{n\to\infty} 2n\cdot x_{2n} \le 0 \iff \\
\lim_{n\to\infty} 2n\cdot x_{2n} = 0 \iff \\
\lim_{n\to\infty} n\cdot x_{n} = 0
$$

Comment: Little problem I see is that your last iff statement isn't correct. Consider a sequence whose even numbers tend to zero but odds dont

Comment: @Anvit But then the sequence is not going to be monotone, is it? which violates the initial conditions, or am i missing something?

Comment: Yep, you're right. However you should mention this else it can lead to confusion. (And possible loss of marks :P )